# Do I need to send the client certificate to another server even if I configured my server with SSL

Tags: ssl, tls1.2, weblogic12c

I am having a doubt regarding SSL certificate. We've some third party vendor who has exposed their services but asks for SSL certifcate to be attached in request.

Our java code is deployed on Weblogic server. Now we have configured SSL certificate (complete chain) in WLS using keystore. it's done on port 9003. Now when I connect with putty to my WLS over SSH and try to curl the test url of the third party vendor, I am getting un authorized error.

Upon inquiring the same to third party vendor, they said I must send my certificate with the request.

Now my question is, `if my server is configured with the SSL certificate, do I need to attach certificate with every request ?`

Answer (score 1):

The certificate which is used to authenticate your server against some browser and the certificate which is used to authenticate yourself as a client against another server are unrelated. While in some cases they might be the same in other cases they are different. In other words: you need to attach the client certificate which is required by the other server with each request. curl will not magically do this for you.